# Points into Multipoint with Shapely

Tags: python, shapely, multipoint

I have a list of `x,y,z` points named simply "A".

I'm trying to convert them to a multipoint with Shapely.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

orig = Point(1.9,2.5,3.1)
destinations = MultiPoint([(A)])
print(destinations)
```

Comment: You don't include the definition of `A`.

Comment: I've solved the issue myself, but I can't accept my answer for 2 days, see below.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you're not going to delete your question, it should be clarified.

Comment: Isn't the first line enough clarification?

Comment: No, it's not. If you're going to provide code, if should contain data that exemplifies what the question describes and shouldn't throw `NameError` trying to access a non-existent variable. These things make the question unclear. A question should be written to be 100% crystal clear with as close as possible to no chance of confusion.

Comment: Your own Q&A provides an example of the problem: your answer also references an `A` variable and passes it to the `list` constructor. Because you never specify what `A` *is*, we can only guess whether it's even necessary. If `A` is a generator, then it might or might not be necessary to store the generator's results. Not accepting a raw generator would be an odd quirk of Shapely that's good to know. But if `A` is a `list` or `tuple`, then calling `list` on it does nothing and the answer would be improved by removing it. But we can't figure this out since we don't know what `A` is.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but I think you  need to replace `A` with `orig` because `A` is not defined, as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

orig = Point(1.9,2.5,3.1)
destinations = MultiPoint([(orig)])
print(destinations)
```

Output:

```
MULTIPOINT Z (1.9 2.5 3.1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the solution, shapely needs to be told it's a list object

```
MultiPoint(points=list(A))
```

Comment: "shapely needs to be told it's a list object" this isn't true and isn't what this syntax does. `list(A)` converts A to a list, so if A was already a list/tuple/iterable, this would convert the data  `A` to a list. Please define A in your question *in code* to clarify what the issue was and how it was resolved.